Angular 17 - How to indicate both else to same ng-template for *ngIf using @if @else
I am trying to convert my code directives from Angular 16 to Angular 17. However, I am unable to achieve the reference in Angular 17 so that for both else it will refer to the same ng-template.
<div *ngIf="movies; else noTracks">
    <div *ngIf="movies.length>0; else noTracks">
        <h6 class="m-b-20 m-t-40 p-b-5 b-b-default f-w-600">Favorites</h6>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Recent</p>
                <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">{{movies[movies.length-1].title}}
                    -
                    {{movies[movies.length-1].rating}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Total</p>
                <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">{{ movies.length}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #noTracks>
    <h6 class="m-b-20 m-t-40 p-b-5 b-b-default f-w-600">Favorites</h6>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Recent</p>
            <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">NA</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Total</p>
            <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">0</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

In Angular 17 I am trying to achieve the above using @if and @else without using || cause for type never error I will get. Further, I want how we can achieve this.
Note: Don't combine @if statements.
@if (movies) {
  @if (movies.length>0) {
    <h6 class="m-b-20 m-t-40 p-b-5 b-b-default f-w-600">Favorites</h6>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Recent</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">{{movies[movies.length-1].title}}
            -
            {{movies[movies.length-1].rating}}</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Total</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">{{ movies.length}}</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  } @else {
    <h6 class="m-b-20 m-t-40 p-b-5 b-b-default f-w-600">Favorites</h6>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Recent</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">NA</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Total</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">0</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}


You can combine both @if conditions into single @if condition @if (movies && movies.length>0)

Or use only this @if (movies?.length) {

thank you but I want to know how I can refer two ng templates

Basically the *ngIfElse syntax is the same as the @if @else statement.
The noTracks <ng-template> remains, and to render the template you need the <ng-container> element with [ngTemplateOutlet].
@if (movies) { 
  @if (movies.length > 0) {
    ...
  } @else { 
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="noTracks"></ng-container>
  } 
} @else { 
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="noTracks"></ng-container>
} 

Make sure that you have imported CommonModule or NgTemplateOulet in your component.
Demo @ StackBlitz
Note that I will prefer combining both @if statements into a single @if which simplifies the (else) template. Since the Post Owner requests to maintain the existing structure as *ngIfElse syntax, I wrote this answer.

Thank you, So we can use ngTemplateOutlet for this I know about ng-container but bot about this.

Just combine the cases (which you already could have done in the previous version):
@if (movies && movies.length > 0) {
<h6 class="m-b-20 m-t-40 p-b-5 b-b-default f-w-600">Favorites</h6>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Recent</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">{{movies[movies.length-1].title}}
            -
            {{movies[movies.length-1].rating}}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Total</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">{{ movies.length}}</h6>
    </div>
</div>
} @else {
<h6 class="m-b-20 m-t-40 p-b-5 b-b-default f-w-600">Favorites</h6>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Recent</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">NA</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="m-b-10 f-w-600">Total</p>
        <h6 class="text-muted f-w-400">0</h6>
    </div>
</div>
}


thank you but I want to know how I can refer two ng templates
